# Can anyone tell me the username and password of WAMP phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am unable to logged in, please tell us me the username and password.
Why we r not asked to set it before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try username: root with blank password.
It is set by default. U can change it too.